# LoadError on line ["55"] of C: cannot load such file -- wdm Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

Tags: sass

Whatever combinations of commands I tried the alert below is coming 
up.

> LoadError on line ["55"] of C: cannot load such file -- wdm Run with
>   --trace to see the full backtrace

How can I resolve this?

**Context:**

- Windows 7 / 64 bit
- Compass 1.0.0.alpha.19
- Sass 3.3.4 (Maptastic Maple)

Config.rb:

```
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
output_style = :expanded
relative_assets = true
line_comments = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem; here's how I fixed it:

First you need to install the Ruby DevKit from here http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ (left hand side, towards the bottom, pick the one for X64 bit).  Installing is a little confusing, but this site helped  a lot http://rubyonwindowsguides.github.io/book/ch02-04.html.

Execute the instructions for both the "init" and the "install" files. Inside the devkit dir, run:

```
$ ruby dk.rb init
$ ruby dk.rb install
```

You are now able to run the `gem install wdm` in the terminal.

Running `compass watch` in the terminal should now give you no errors.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be resolved by uninstalling sass and compass and reinstalling the latest version.

I got this issue by installing an older version of compass which ended up conflicting with things. To uninstall, do the following from the command line:

```
gem uninstall sass
gem uninstall compass
```

Then do the reverse and reinstall them latest version

```
gem install sass
gem install compass
```

The devkit approach seemed like overkill so I'm glad this solution worked.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was (after a ton of trial and error) just `gem update --system`.

Comment: Wow! Strangely enough, this worked for me too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but it was to do with a missing requirement.  My error was:

```
LoadError on line ["55"] of /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- compass-normalize
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

I was working on a project whose frontend build is done with gulp, so wasn't sure of how it all worked, but after seeing `require: ['compass-normalize'],` in the gulpfile, and running `gem install compass-normalize`, everything worked.